# ajax response returns empty on live server but has value on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

my ajax file returns value on my local host but when I uploaded it on live server it returns an empty array.

this is what's inside the file my ajax/jquery calls

```
include '../../components/db.php';
$res_date = $_POST['res_date'];

 $query = "SELECT t.timeasd from time t left join (select time_reserved, date_reservation from RESERVATIONS where date_reservation = '$res_date') as q on t.timeasd = q.time_reserved where q.date_reservation is null AND t.status='active'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $timeslots=array();
 while ($myrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
        $timeslot=$myrow['timeasd'];
        array_push($timeslots,$timeslot);
      }
 echo json_encode($timeslots);
```

it worked when I changed the query to

```
SELECT * from time
```

but I am using the former query on my localhost database and it works perfectly

Comment: does your live database contains the files ?

Comment: *"this is my ajax file"* - Huh? That's php and mysql, not ajax.

Comment: @Nicolas yes it does have the same ones I have on my localhost database

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner what I meant was, that is what's inside the file my ajax/jquery calls

Comment: Do you have any SQL errors ?

Comment: no I dont, it shows the result of the query

Comment: @Nicolas sorry. it was just a stupid mistake. I just realized that live hosting is very picky with case sensitivity. my query should have been "reservations" instead of "RESERVATIONS"

Comment: *"I just realized that live hosting is very picky with case sensitivity"* - Most likely on a \*NIX box/OS.

Comment: `mysqli_error($conn)` would have helped during testing and php's error reporting.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yup, I'll make sure to add that in my queries in the future, thanks!